# DevExpress how to bind a string a to simple TextEdit control?

Tags: c#, devexpress, controls, bind, textedit

I have a simple TextEdit control I have dropped onto a form.

I have a class I have created which holds various settings for the application.

How do I bind a member variable of my app settings class to a textedit control?

I wish I could specify that I want it bound to a string, like: public string MyEditBoxValue;

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string setting1 = (string)Settings.Default["MySetting1"];
textEdit1.Text = setting1;
```